# Default value of select element angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen other similar questions but none of the answers helped in my case.

My controller loads an object and an array of an objects and I assign it to two variables.

Array:

```
customers.getCustomers() //pobieram odpowiedniego klienta
                    .then(function successCallback(response){
                        $scope.klienci = response.data.data;

                        console.log('Klienci', $scope.klienci[0])
                    }, function errorCallback(response){
                        console.log('Nie załadowałem użytkownika:'+response.status);
                        console.log(response.statusText);
                });
```

and single object:

```
customers.getCustomer($scope.serwis.id) //pobieram odpowiedniego klienta
                    .then(function successCallback(response){
                        $scope.customer = response.data;
                        console.log('Klient', response.data)
                    }, function errorCallback(response){
                        console.log('Nie załadowałem użytkownika:'+response.status);
                        console.log(response.statusText);
                });
```

The first object in the array of an objects is exactly the same as the single object so:

```
$scope.klienci[0] === $scope.customer
```

to be specific:

```
$scope.klienci[0] == {__metadata: Object, id: 1, firstName: "Jan", lastName: "Kowalski", telephone: "123132132"}
$scope.customer == {__metadata: Object, id: 1, firstName: "Jan", lastName: "Kowalski", telephone: "123132132"}
```

My html fragment is here:

```
<select ng-model="customer.id" ng-options="klient.firstName for klient in klienci" class="form-control"></select>
```

Firebug code:

```
<select ng-model="customer.id" ng-options="klient.firstName for klient in klienci track by klient.id" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option label="Jan" value="17">Jan</option>
<option label="Thomas" value="18">Thomas</option>
<option label="Stanislaw" value="19">Stanislaw</option>
<option label="Katarzyna" value="20">Katarzyna</option>
</select>
```

The first selection option is blank but if I use `ng-model="customer"` it will work but I won't be able to pass all the fields data in single `$scope.customer` object when saving.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customer.id` can't match with `klient.firstName`, 
if you want the select option has a default value,you can use
    `<select ng-model="customer.id" ng-options="klient.id as klient.firstName for klient in klienci" class="form-control"></select>`

Comment: Thank you @roman-hutnyk and @cyrus-zhou for pointing out the `klient.firstName` mistake. However, I still cannot get default value using `ng-model="customer.id"` I get following: 
`<select ng-model="customer.id" ng-options="klient.id as klient.firstName for klient in klienci track by klient.id" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty"><option value="?" selected="selected"></option><option label="Michal" value="1">Michal</option><option label="Jan" value="2">Jan</option><option label="Stanislaw" value="3">Stanislaw</option></select>`

Only `ng-model="customer"` works

Comment: It seems that `track by` was an issue in my last case.
Correct version:
`<select ng-model="customer.id" ng-options="klient.id as klient.firstName + ' ' + klient.lastName for klient in klienci" class="form-control"></select> `

Comment: I think you browser auto add `track by klient.id`

Answer (score 1):

You are taking first name for options, but binding to the object when specifying:

```
ng-model="customer"
```

You should either use object for options:

```
ng-options="klient for klient in klienci"
```

Or firstname for a model:

```
ng-model="customer.firstname"
```